# HttpClient Parallel Requests Timeout using Task.WhenAll when one request times out

Tags: c#, task, dotnet-httpclient

i making ~20 http get requests using one httpclient, this httpclient is long living, means it is not packed into a using statement. As the webservice is normally pretty fast (response time ~200ms) i set the timeout to 5sec.

Now i ran into the problem, if one request runs into that timeout all other requests get cancelled. Is this the normal behaviour?

Here is the code i am using to make conccurent calls

```
public async Task GetAll()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(x => x.Select(xx => GetData(xx.Id));
}
```

Code to call the api:

```
    public async Task GetData(int id)
    {
        string payload = "";
        try
        {
            var resp = await base.GetAsync($"/apis/v2/getdata/{id}");
            if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                Console.WriteLine("Error");

            payload = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(payload);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
```

My Base HttpClient Class

```
public class MyHttpClient : System.Net.Http.HttpClient
{
    public Logger Log  { get; set; }
}
```

If i run the task in sequential order everything works fine, but when i run them in parallel and one task runs into a timeout all other not finished task will be cancelled.

Comment: This can't be your actual code. For a start, it wouldn't even compile because it's missing the `async` modifier. What is `base` here? What does `base.GetAsync` do?

Comment: If set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to 20, would that fix the issue? ( because default limit is 2 in .Net Framework, reference :  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2017/10/23/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework/ )

Comment: @Stefan D'oh, I didn't see it was 2 distinct functions. Still, we need to know what `base` is, not sure how you think it is an `HttpClient` (`base` is a reserved word so it cannot be a variable name)

Comment: @DavidG GetData is a method in my HttpClient Class which simply derives from System.Net.HttpClient, so base.GetAsync only calls the System.Net.HttpClient.GetAsync method. I have not tried the DefaultConnectionLimit. I first wanted to understand how the HttpClient behaves if one request times out while others are still running.

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth there's a default limit of 2 concurrent connections per domain, enforced by all browsers and .NET itself. You can overwrite in the HttpClientHandler settings. On the other hand, it may be the *API* that's blocking due to blocking database connections, locks or inefficient coding.

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is a domain-wide setting. You can change the setting per HttpClient through the [HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Fildor you are right it still needs async (just edited it) but this does not solve the problem, i just copied a code snipped which should describe how i create concurrent calls, sorry for that bad example.

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth can you provide us the code for the base to try to understant how your code work and wy you have this probleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8